# Export Members in AzureAD Group

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

Running script to export all Members in a specific AzureAD Group, but only get half and not all users.

I verified that there are members in Azure Portal, but export only gives me half

This is the script I ran:

```
Get-AzureADgroupmember -objectid "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" | get-azureaduser | Export-Csv -path C:\temp\memberexport.csv
```

Any reason on why this is exporting only half and not all users in group?

Thank you,

Comment: Try using `-All` optional parameter with `Get-AzureADGroupMember` command. I think it might be returning you only a subset like first 100 or something like that. I'm not sure about the default number, but using `-All` should probably take care of that.

Comment: odd, yes. i added '-All 1' after the object ID and worked Get-AzureADgroupmember -objectid "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -All 1 | get-azureaduser | Export-Csv -path C:\temp\memberexport.csv @RohitSaigal can you add this for the answer so I can put it as solved? Thank you.

Comment: ok sure I will add.. glad to know that it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't specify `-All` as well as `-Top` optional parameters, then `Get-AzureADGroupMember` command may return you only a default number of records (like say 100. I'm not sure on this exact number).

So if you want all the members, try to specify that explicitly by using `-All` parameter. Example below:

```
Get-AzureADgroupmember -objectid "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -All $true | get-azureaduser | Export-Csv -path C:\temp\memberexport.csv
```